# JSON decode - Object

Tags: php, json, decode

Below is the JSON I decoded with:

```
  $reqarr = json_decode($message, true);
```

Here is the decoded JSON:

```
{
"update_id" :720650368,
"message"   :
        {
         "message_id"   :14,
         "from"         :{  
                    "id":876963516,
                    "is_bot":false,
                    "first_name":"MIS",
                    "last_name":"SKH",
                    "username":"SKHMIS",
                    "language_code":"en"},
        "chat"          :{
                    "id":876963516,
                    "first_name":"MIS",
                    "last_name":"SKH",
                    "username":"SKHMIS",
                    "type":"private"},
        "date"      :1557738572,
        "text"      :"/attendance",
        "entities"  :[{"offset":0,"length":11,"type":"bot_command"}]
        }
}
```

There is a key called `entities` with object type **array**, which is different when compared to the other keys.

I could not get the value this this:

```
    $typ = $reqarr['message']['entities']['type']
```

I also tried with a **for-each loop**, as well, but it didn't work.

How to get the value of `type` in `entities`?

Comment: Have you tried `$typ = $reqarr['message']['entities'][0]['type'];` ?

Comment: After using the `json_decode` there no further object, all they are array elemet , access the type using `$reqarr['message']['entities'][0]['type']`

Comment: @RakeshJakhar Completely misunderstood the JSON String :) My mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do:

```
$typ = $reqarr['message']['entities'][0]['type'];
```

Output:-https://3v4l.org/KQc2s

Comment: @MangeshSathe  based on OP data, yes. if it have multiple types, then do `foreach()` on `entities` and get all types. in that case `[0]` not required

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(!isset($reqarr['message']['entities'][0])){
    $reqarr['message']['entities']=array($reqarr['message']['entities']);
}

foreach($reqarr['message']['entities'] as $entity){
   var_dump($entities);
   die();
}
```

Comment: Can you explain all that further? What does this code do? What makes you think that it solves the problem? Keep in mind that others should be able to learn from your answer

Comment: @NicoHaase,I am trying to give solution ,Where if the array is not set or if you are trying to read the array values i am applying check here only.

Comment: Please add all such information to the answer by editing it, not to the comment section

Comment: @NicoHaase,sure :)